# Decay $\Sigma^{0} \to \Lambda + \gamma$ - computing the mean lifetime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

In the decay $\Sigma^{0} \to \Lambda + \gamma$ (such that the $\Sigma^{0}$ is located at $\mathbf{r}=0$) has a Hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H = \frac{1}{  m_{\Sigma} + m_{\Lambda} }\ \hat{T}\ \boldsymbol{\sigma} \ \cdot ( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} ) \big|_{\mathbf{r}=0} 
$$

Where $\hat{T}$ is an operator turning the $\Sigma^{0}$ into the $\Lambda$ (leaving the spin-state unchanged).

I'm supposed to calculate the mean lifetime of the $\Sigma^{0}$ (assuming the $\Sigma^{0}$ is at rest, and that I can neglect the recoil of the $\Lambda$).

How do I approach this problem? Obviously I need a non-relativistic approach. Do I use the Born approximation to get a scattering amplitude, and then try and derive the decay rate from there? I know that the inverse of the decay rate gives me the lifetime.

Comment: If the subject matter were different, this sort of question would be closed as "homework-like," especially since the meat of the question (v2) is "How do I approach this?" rather than something like "I've tried using the Born approximation, but got confusing result X." However, if the community were going to let some homework questions survive, I'd hope for interesting and advanced questions like this one. Not least because I have forgotten how to find the answer myself :-)

Comment: Having said that: 'tis the season for take-home final exams, so answerers are encouraged to give conceptual guidance rather than complete answers.

Comment: I totally appreciate that, in fact it is a homework question. I've just got no idea how to approach the problem. I feel like the Born approximation simply can't be applied here, as this is not a scattering problem (also, there's not even a potential $V$ given with which I could evaluate the scattering amplitude with Born's approx). I'm not looking for answers at all, rather I'd just hope for a hint as to how to start this problem.

Comment: Greg.Paul: Unwelcomely, my comment regarding the earlier version of your question has disappeared (without notification to me). Hereby I resubmit it:
 $$~$$
Greg.Paul: "_Where $\tau$ is an operator [...]_" -- Please consider denoting this operator instead $\hat\tau$, and reserving the symbol "$\tau$" rather for denoting [mean life](https://www.google.de/search?q=pdg+%22mean+life%22). 
$$~$$
`1:` Thanks for how you edited your question. (I therefore issued +1 already this morning.) But even more importantly (to me) `2:` [... contd.]

Comment: ... But even more importantly (to me) `2:` ["_time_" is understood as synonymous to "indication (position of the small hand) of a clock"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/156?highlightText=%22my%20substituting%22), which is **not duration**. And `3:` Sorry that I can't help with answering your question at the moment.

Comment: An update: having skimmed through (my copies of) [Blatt-Weisskopf](https://www.google.com/#q=Blatt+Weisskopf) and [deShalit-Feshbach](https://www.google.com/#q=de+Shalit+Feshbach); through [this readily available thesis (p. 141)](https://inspirehep.net/record/235272?ln=de) and relevant references therein, unfortunately/curiously I've not ever seen quite the specific ansatz mentioned in your question (especially regarding the sum of masses in the denominator). So besides, I can answer only very generally: (try to) use "[Fermi's Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule)".

Comment: @Greg did you finally solve this problem? If yes, you could post the answer